# Android shared database development

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Please give me some light regarding to this situation. I'm new in android development and I don't know how to handle this. I need to have my application to be install in many Android devices at least two device. Now I want both of them to share single database at the same time because there will be data to be process by one another. I'm a full pledge ASP.Net programmer so my mindset regarding this situation is to build a host device then the other one will connect to the same network as where the host is connected or is there any other way how this two can be connected then share the same database.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a REST api and talk to it with all android devices.  The server must control the database to make sure that nobody reads or writes the same database rows at the same time.